# How to show archived message from core data in to the chat tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, xmppframework

I am able to get the archived messages. but I can't figure out how to show it in the tableview as I have already showing the online chat with it. so can anyone help me how to show the old messages before online chat to load it in the tableview?

Here I am getting the archived messages:

```
 -(void)print:(NSMutableArray*)messages_arc{
@autoreleasepool {

    for (XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject *message in messages_arc) {

       // NSString *server=@"@www.demoseocousa.com";
   // chatWithUser=[chatWithUser stringByAppendingString:server];


        NSXMLElement *element = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithXMLString:message.messageStr error:nil];
        NSLog(@"to param is %@",[element attributeStringValueForName:@"to"]);

        s = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [s setObject:message.body forKey:@"msg"];

        if ([[element attributeStringValueForName:@"to"] isEqualToString:chatWithUser]) {

            [s setObject:sender forKey:@"sender"];

        }
        else
        {
            [s setObject:chatWithUser forKey:@"sender"];
        }

        [messages addObject:s];

       // NSString *t=message.timestamp
       // [s setObject:t forKey:"time"];

        NSLog(@"bareJid param is %@",message.bareJid);
        NSLog(@"bareJidStr param is %@",message.bareJidStr);
        NSLog(@"body param is %@",message.body);
        NSLog(@"timestamp param is %@",message.timestamp);
        NSLog(@"outgoing param is %d",[message.outgoing intValue]);
        NSLog(@"***************************************************");
    }
    }
messages=messages_arc;
}
```

And this is where I am populating the tableView for online chat:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MessageCellIdentifier";
UIImage *bgImage = nil;

SMMessageViewTableCell *cell = (SMMessageViewTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[SMMessageViewTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


   NSDictionary *x = (NSDictionary *) [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   NSString *sender2 = [x objectForKey:@"sender"];


   NSLog(@"CHATWITHUSER : %@",chatWithUser);

    NSString *message = [x objectForKey:@"msg"];
    NSString *time = [x objectForKey:@"time"];

    CGSize  textSize = { 260.0, 10000.0 };
    CGSize size2 = [message sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]
                      constrainedToSize:textSize
                          lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    size2.width += (padding/2);

    cell.messageContentView.text = message;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

  NSLog(@"CHATWITH %@,",chatWithUser);

    if ([sender2 isEqualToString:chatWithUser])
    { // left aligned

        bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"03.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:30  topCapHeight:19];

        [cell.messageContentView setFrame:CGRectMake(padding, padding*2, size2.width, size2.height)];

        [cell.bgImageView setFrame:CGRectMake( cell.messageContentView.frame.origin.x - padding/2,
                                              cell.messageContentView.frame.origin.y - padding/2,
                                              size2.width+padding,
                                              size2.height+padding)];
    }

    if ([sender2 isEqualToString:[[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] myJID] bare]]) {

        bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Aqua.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24  topCapHeight:10];

        [cell.messageContentView setFrame:CGRectMake(320 - size2.width - padding,
                                                     padding*2,
                                                     size2.width,
                                                     size2.height)];

        [cell.bgImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.messageContentView.frame.origin.x - padding/2,
                                              cell.messageContentView.frame.origin.y - padding/2,
                                              size2.width+padding,
                                              size2.height+padding)];

    }

    cell.bgImageView.image = bgImage;
 //   cell.textLabel.text=[[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"msg"];
    cell.senderAndTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", sender2, time];

 NSLog(@"The MEssage==>%@",messages);
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
return cell;

}
```

So please suggest me how to do it and where should i reloadData to tableView as here I am loading it in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: I actually didn't understand what you are asking. What is online chat?

Comment: @Sushil here online chat means when both users are online and chatting.

Comment: So you want to show old chat?

Comment: @Sushil yeah at the beginning

Comment: @Sushil the problem is that as the array I am getting for archived message is of type 'XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject' and for instant message the array I am getting is of type 'XMPPMessage'